# Expanding QTreeView Item From ModelIndex

Tags: python, qt, qtreeview, qmodelindex

How can I expand a QTreeView item knowing it's modelIndex. I'm trying to call the following piece of code and it doesn't throw any errors but it does not expand the treeview item...

```
parentIndex = self.categoryModel.indexFromItem(parent)
if parentIndex.isValid():
    self.uiTreeView.setExpanded(parentIndex, True)
```

To test, select the first item in the list and click the Add button. When a user adds a new category i want it to expand the item it's being added to.

[image]

```
import os, sys
from Qt import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

################################################################################
# Widgets
################################################################################
class CategoryView(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(250,400)

        self.uiAdd = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add')

        self.categoryModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.categoryModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Items'])

        self.categoryProxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.categoryProxyModel.setSourceModel(self.categoryModel)
        self.categoryProxyModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.categoryProxyModel.setSortCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.categoryProxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)

        self.uiTreeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.uiTreeView.setModel(self.categoryProxyModel)
        self.uiTreeView.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.uiTreeView.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiAdd)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiTreeView)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Selections
        self.categorySelection = self.uiTreeView.selectionModel()

        # Signals
        self.uiAdd.clicked.connect(self.slotAddNewCategory)

        parent = self.categoryModel.invisibleRootItem()
        parent.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem('Fruit'))


    # Methods
    def getSelectedItems(self):
        items = []
        for proxyIndex in self.categorySelection.selectedIndexes():
            sourceIndex = self.categoryProxyModel.mapToSource(proxyIndex)
            item = self.categoryModel.itemFromIndex(sourceIndex)
            items.append(item)
        return items


    def slotAddNewCategory(self):
        text, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name:')

        if ok:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)

            parent = self.categoryModel.invisibleRootItem()
            items = self.getSelectedItems()
            if len(items) == 1:
                parent = items[0]

            parent.appendRow(item)

            parentIndex = self.categoryModel.indexFromItem(parent)
            print parentIndex.data()
            if parentIndex.isValid():
                self.uiTreeView.setExpanded(parentIndex, True)


################################################################################
# Unit Testing
################################################################################
def test_CategoryView():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = CategoryView()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
    test_CategoryView()
    # test_PainterSettingsDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer found here... [How to expand top-level QTreeview items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596847/how-to-expand-top-level-qtreeview-items)

```
parentIndex = self.categoryModel.indexFromItem(parent)
px = self.categoryProxyModel.mapFromSource(parentIndex)

if parentIndex.isValid():
    self.uiTreeView.setExpanded(px, True)
```